# Is the iPhone SE compatible with iPhone 5 cases?

Tags: case, iphone

Are the dimensions and the placements of the ports and buttons identical on the iPhone SE and iPhone 5 (which is [physically compatible with the iPhone 5S](/q/101548/21748))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the cases are compatible and apple has confirmed it.

Source: http://9to5mac.com/2016/03/21/expanded-iphone-case-lineup/